# How to add conditionals to Gurobi quicksum()?

Tags: python, sum, gurobi

I have a constraint like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQmSw.png)

with python code (and j!=i)

```
        # 3.9
        for i in range(self.noCells):
            for t in range(self.noHours - 1):
                self.model.addConstr(
                    self.alpha * self.SoH[i, t] * self.soc[i, t] +
                    quicksum(self.gcrPower[l] * self.g[i, t, l] for l in range(self.noL)) / self.noCells +
                    quicksum(self.solPower[m] * self.r[i, t, m] for m in range(self.noM)) / self.noCells -
                    quicksum(self.dcrPower[n] * self.d[i, t, n] for n in range(self.noN)) / self.noCells +
                    quicksum(self.b_plus[j, i, t] for j in range(self.noCells) and j!=i) -
                    quicksum(self.b_minus[i, j, t] for j in range(self.noCells) and j!=i) -
                    self.SoH[i, t+1] * self.soc[i, t+1] == 0
                )
```

but it will raise a problem that j is not defined?

How to solve it ? Thansk everybody.

to find a correct code

Comment: Hi, I think you need `if j!=i` instead of `and j!=i`

Comment: U r totally correct. Many thanks~~~